# Why I am getting "This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection"

Tags: angular, jestjs, babel-jest

I am getting an error when testing a component in Angular 11, and I am not sure why.

```
    This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
    This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

      at ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep (../../node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5098:15)
      at NodeInjectorFactory.factory (..\..\ng:\LoginComponent\ɵfac.js:5:42)
      at getNodeInjectable (../../node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3872:48)
```

The LoginComponent constructor is:

```
  constructor(
    public loginSvc: LoginService,
    public iamService: IamService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private growlService: GrowlerService,
    private matDialog: MatDialog,
    public dialogForm: MatDialog,
    @Inject(ENVIRONMENT) private environment: Environment
  ) {

  }
```

That makes index 0 LoginService, which I have mocked in the testbed

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        MatDialogModule
      ],
      declarations: [LoginComponent, CallbackComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LoginService, useFactory: () => {
            return {} as LoginService;
          }
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
```

my jest.config:

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'authorization',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
          'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer'
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/libs/authorization',
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|html)$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '../../node_modules/(?!hashjs-es\')'
  ]
};
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it known for sure that the error refers to this component and not another?

Comment: I was hoping someone could tell me I was reading the stack right/wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that

```
@Inject(ENVIRONMENT) private environment: Environment
```

should be either

```
@Inject("ENVIRONMENT") private environment: Environment
```

or

```
@Inject(Environment) private environment: Environment
```

Is ENVIRONMENT being provided in your module?
perhaps you need to provide it in TestBed too:

```
{ provide: ENVIRONMENT, useValue: environment }
```

Comment: ENVIRONMENT is the defined token.  Testbed has  { provide: ENVIRONMENT, useValue: {} as environment }